# Getter not found: 'location_city_sharp' for Icons.location_city_sharp

Tags: flutter, dart, icons

I am using material Icons avaliable in material UI flutter. But it throws error.

```
icon: Icon(Icons.location_city_sharp,color: Colors.orange,)),
```

I have checked user-material-design is true in pubspec.yaml.

Still It throws error:

```
Error: Getter not found: 'location_city_sharp'.
```

Any workaround with this? Thanks.

Edit:

The code is following:

```
FancyOnBoarding(
    pageList: [
      PageModel(
        color: Colors.orange,
        heroImagePath: "assets/images/introduction1.png",
        title: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Welcome to TakeOut",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 35),
          ),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              "Find all popular and best restaurants of city",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        // icon: Icon(
        //   Icons.location_city_sharp,
        //   color: Colors.orange,
        // )
      )....
```

Comment: Are you sure ? because these are static members and not getters

Comment: yes, when i run `flutter run`, it throws this error.

Comment: Works fine on my machine.